# Do I need to use a definite article?

Tags: grammar, colloquial, definite-article

Is this correct?

> Ich freue mich, dass es Wochenende ist.

Or should I say:

> Ich freue mich, dass es *das* Wochenende ist.

With or without the article? I have definitely heard the first, but I am not sure if it is informal/slang.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your example it is absolutely correct to leave out the article. The pronoun *"es"* is used here as a placeholder to further specify a following condition. We can better see the grammatical construction if we split the subordinate clause:

> Es ist Wochenende.

In this case *"Wochenende"* is the condition for *"es"* as it would also be the case with other conditions like e.g.

> Es ist Nacht. Es ist Sonntag. Es ist Feierabend.

Note that in case we further elaborate the condition (e.g. by using an adjective) we then need an article:

> Es ist das erste Wochenende im Jahr. Es ist das schönste Wochenende seit langem.

Answer (score 9):

"Ich freue mich, dass es Wochenende ist" is correct, but the most idiomatic form is without "es": "Ich freue mich, dass Wochenende ist".

"Das Wochenende" in this context would always refer to a specific weekend (e.g., the first weekend in April), never to weekends (or whatever happens to be the current weekend) in general.

Answer (score 3):

`Ich freue mich, dass es Wochenende ist.` is a general remark: `I'm happy, it is weekend`.

`Ich freue mich, dass es das Wochenende ist.` is correct, but it sounds a bit strange. It has more the meaning `I'm happy, it is this special weekend`.  In German I would prefer `Ich freue mich, dass es dieses Wochenende ist.`

I'm not sure, but I have the impression `Ich freue mich, dass es das Wochenende ist.` has some dialect influence. I'm from south of Germany and I would say in dialect something like `Ich freu mich, dass es des Wochenend isch.`. The `dieses Wochenende` has a more upper German impression on me.